# Upgrade default install of CouchDB on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I've installed ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and ran `apt-get install couchdb`. This installed 0.10.0, however the newest is 0.11.0 and I would like to install that from source.

What's the appropriate way of upgrading the current install to the newest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couchdb installs very nicely and fairly easily on Ubuntu 10.04.

1. Copy your database files somewhere else.  They are probably in /var/lib/couchdb.
2. Copy your /etc/couchdb/local.ini file (if you've changed it at all) somewhere else.
3. use apt-get to remove the couchdb packages.
4. make sure that all of files installed by the packages are removed.  If you don't do this you may get strange errors later.
5. then follow the instructions on the [Installing on Ubuntu](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu) page Eric Edin linked to. You will need to make the adjustments mentioned for 10.04, and the bit about /etc/ld.so.conf.d/xulrunner.conf toward the bottom.
6. Copy your database files back into /var/lib/couchdb and put any changes back into the local.ini file  and restart couchdb

Comment: Nice. Also, in my case the couchdb command kept giving error messages like `{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return` after upgrading. I had to manually kill the process (after backing up the `/var/lib/couchdb` and `/etc/couchdb/local.ini`) and restart it (and do http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043164/896657)

Answer (score 2):

On the CouchDB wiki there are instructions for building 0.11 from source.

[Installing on Ubuntu](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu)